# Defining a Bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to show: $X$ is complete normed space, and $x \not= y$ then we can define a linear functional such that $f(x-y)=1$

I am not sure how to tackle this.My approach was using a the Baire Category theorem, Trying to show this is possible for an open set in $X$, then using the Hahn Banach theorem to extend this $f$.

Let $E_f= \{f \in V^* : f(x-y)=1 \} $

This set is closed. Now for each $x,y \in X $ there is some $f$ such that $f(x-y)=1$ (I have a problem here I am assuming my result)
and aiming then to say that $X= \bigcup E_{f_i}$ thus because X is complete metric space there is a set that is nowhere dense.

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

It is an application of Hahn Banach Theorem.

Let $z=x-y$ and $Y=\{\lambda z: \lambda\in\mathbb R\}$. Then $Y$ is a subspace of $X$.

Define on $Y$ a linear functional
$$
f(\lambda z)=\lambda.
$$
According to Hahn Banach, this extends to a bounded linear functional on $X$.

Comment: This is much easier than what I was thinking. Thank you, small question when we apply the Hahn Banach we need some p to dominate the f on Y. So we define the $f(\lambda z)=\lambda \leq |\lambda| = p(\lambda z)$

Answer (score 0):

Write $a=x-y$, consider the subspace generated by $a$, i.e. $A=\left\{ta\mid t \in \mathbb{C}\right\}$.

Define $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:ta\mapsto t$.

Now using the Hahn-Banach extension theorem, we can extend $f$ to $X$.

Edit: I was 5 seconds too late :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an important consequence of Hahn-Banach theorem:

Let $X$ be a Banch space and $x_0\ne 0$ an element of it. Then there is a bounded linear functional on $X$ such that $f(x_0)=||x_0||$ and $||f||=1$.

Put $x_0 =x-y$ and define the desired bounded linear functional to be $g={1\over ||x_0||}f$.